# Pass parameters to SQL CTEs using Python Pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, common-table-expression

**I am using pandas.io.sql to execute a SQL script that contains CTE and would like to do something like this:**

```
import pandas.io.sql as psql
param1 = 'park'
param2 = 'zoo'

sqlstr = ("""WITH CTE_A AS (    
                          SELECT * 
                          FROM A 
                          WHERE A.Location = param1),
                  CTE_B AS (
                            SELECT * 
                            FROM B 
                            WHERE B.Location = param2)
            SELECT A.*, B.*
            FROM C
            INNER JOIN A
            ON C.something = A.something
            INNER JOIN B
            ON C.something = B.something 
            WHERE C.combined = param1 || param2
            )
```

**I would like to do something like this**

```
    result = psql.frame_query(sqlstr, con = db, params = (param1,param2))
```

**Could anyone help me in passing the two parameters using Pandas?**

Comment: Is there some way we could get traffic to this? The only way I know how to do this is use pyodbc to do the data pull and pass the object to a dataframe. https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted#Parameters

Answer (score 2):

The only way that I know how to do something like this is to do the following. It doesn't however take advantage of the psql package in Pandas.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas

conn = pyodbc.connect('yourconnectionstring')
curs = conn.cursor()

param1 = 'park'
param2 = 'zoo'

sqlstr = """WITH CTE_A AS (    
                          SELECT * 
                          FROM A 
                          WHERE A.Location = param1),
                  CTE_B AS (
                            SELECT * 
                            FROM B 
                            WHERE B.Location = param2)
            SELECT A.*, B.*
            FROM C
            INNER JOIN A
            ON C.something = A.something
            INNER JOIN B
            ON C.something = B.something 
            WHERE C.combined = ?|| ?;"""
q = curs.execute(sqlstr,[param1,param2]).fetchall()
df = pandas.DataFrame(q)

curs.close()
conn.close()
```

This passes parameters to avoid SQL injection and ends with a DataFrame object containing your results

Answer (score 0):

When using pandas.io.sql in combination with mysql.connector the syntax is as follows:

```
import pandas.io.sql as psql 
import mysql.connector as mysql 

db = mysql.connector(host="localhost",user="user",passwd="password")
hour = 7
result = psql.read_sql("select * from table where 
`hour` > %(hour)s and `name` = %(name)s",con=db,params={'hour':hour,'name':'John'})
```

So just enter %(name)s in the query, replace 'name' with whatever name you want. And add an dictionary for params.

I this option does add '' to the string so if for example you need to use it in a table name then this doesn't work. I use regex to clean the string for this. i.e.

```
import re
table_name = re.sub(r'[\W]', ' ',table_name)
(use r'[\W_]' if the table name also doesn't have underscores)
```